# Survival analysis in survey dropouts?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I am working with a survey data set and am curious about who abandoned it before finishing all the questions.  I have information on how many questions each respondent answered (no skipping allowed) and I also know additional data about each respondent.  Would it be appropriate to use survival analysis to determine what makes someone more or less likely to finish the survey?  It seems obvious, but I haven't been able to find a good guide in the literature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a question to better ubderstand: is this s cross-sectional study, i.e. subjects were simply  asked to complete the question of the survey without any follow-up?

Comment: That is correct.  The data are basically like this:

Comment: (obviously simplified):
Q1-Q25: Survey questions, mostly Likert scales.  Shows how many questions a given person has answered.
D1-D10: Demographic information, based on outside data.

I can analyze who finished the survey and who didn't but I am looking for something that gives us more information and survival analysis came to mind as a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Survival analysis is a time-dependent analysis that is typically used for follow-up data in prospective or retrospective studies. Since in this case we have a cross-sectional study where no follow-up was performed, this analysis is not appropriate. The correct approach is to use logistic regression, which explores predictors of a dichotomous event in a time-independent fashion. You can set finishing/no finishing of the survey as the dependent dichotomous variable and test the other variables as predictors in a multivariable model. The regression will identify independent variables associated with the probability of finishing the survey.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  Now I understand why the form of analysis isn't used in surveys, exactly what prompted me to ask.